# Apache mod_rewrite: perform http to https redirect on URL that has already undergone a URL Rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

Issue has as follows:

I am performing URL rewrites to create canonical URL's from URL's with parameters. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^somename/(.*)/(.*.html)$ index.php?pram1=someparam&param2=$1&param3=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Now, I also want to check if the page is using the https protocol, and if not, make a 301 Redirect.

Problem: Apache does not seem to recongnize the new (canonical URL) when using REQUEST_URI. Instead, REQUEST_URI returns the index.php?... URL.

This makes it impossible to get the current (canonical URL), check for HTTPS and redirect to it if necessary.

For example,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (somename)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

won't work at all, since (somename) is not in the URI (remeber, {REQUEST_URI} holds the original URL).

I could match against QUERY_STRING, but then the redirection takes me to the original URL

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (param1)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

I have been searching on the internet for the last hour for a solution on this, but I could not come up with something. I thought maybe there is a way to create an enviroment variable to hold the new (canonical) URL, but had no luck finding a way to do this either.

Any suggestions that might help?

Answer (score 0):

> won't work at all, since (somename) is not in the URI (remeber, {REQUEST_URI} holds the original URL).

Incorrect, `%{REQUEST_URI}` is literally the current URI, after whatever mangling it's been through via mod_rewite or other modules during the URL-file-mapping processing pipeline. What you want is probably `%{THE_REQUEST}`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(somename/[^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%1 [R=301,L]
```

However, I suspect that isn't really the issue. The issue is the order which you've placed your rules and that the redirect doesn't have the `L` flag. This should do what you want:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^somename/(.*)/(.*.html)$ index.php?pram1=someparam&param2=$1&param3=$2 [QSA,L]
```